# loopback4 path enum validation

Tags: typescript, validation, loopback4

I would like to validate the path in loopback by using decorators. Currently trying this, but loopback does not honor the validation. I beliveve this is an issue with the framework, but would like to be sure Im not missing an alternative or doing anything wrong.

for the following, I would expect calling GET /foo/hello to return a 400 error, but the framework simply calls the handler. how would I validate the path adheres to the enums?

```
@operation('get', 'foo/{type}`)
public async getFoo(
  @param({
    name: 'type',
    in: 'path',
    description: 'Type of the Resource Group',
    required: true,
    schema: { type: 'string', enum:  ['type1', 'type2']},
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the enum constraints using AJV in the model definition, i.e. using `jsonSchema` instead of `schema` in your above example. See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Validation-REST-layer.html.

```
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    jsonSchema: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['type1', 'type2'],
    },
  })
  fooType: string;
```

UPDATED:
There's a PR in progress to add validation to the OpenAPI parameter. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/6285 for progress. Thanks.